# How do I tear down observer relationship in multithreaded C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, design-patterns, oop

I have a Subject which offers `Subscribe(Observer*)` and `Unsubscribe(Observer*)` to clients.  Subject runs in its own thread (from which it calls `Notify()` on subscribed Observers) and a mutex protects its internal list of Observers.

I would like client code - which I don't control - to be able to safely delete an Observer after it is unsubscribed.  How can this be achieved?

- Holding the mutex - even a recursive
  mutex - while I notify observers
  isn't an option because of the
  deadlock risk.
- I could mark an observer for removal
  in the Unsubscribe call and remove it
  from the Subject thread.  Then
  clients could wait for a special
  'Safe to delete' notification.  This
  looks safe, but is onerous for
  clients.

**Edit**

Some illustrative code follows.  The problem is how to prevent Unsubscribe happening while Run is at the 'Problem here' comment.  Then I could call back on a deleted object.  Alternatively, if I hold the mutex throughout rather than making the copy, I can deadlock certain clients.

```
#include <set>
#include <functional>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

class Observer
{
public:
    void Notify() {}
};

class Subject
{
public:
    Subject() : t(bind(&Subject::Run, this))
    {
    }

    void Subscribe(Observer* o)
    {
        mutex::scoped_lock l(m);
        observers.insert(o);
    }

    void Unsubscribe(Observer* o)
    {
        mutex::scoped_lock l(m);
        observers.erase(o);
    }

    void Run()
    {
        for (;;)
        {
            WaitForSomethingInterestingToHappen();
            set<Observer*> notifyList;
            {
                mutex::scoped_lock l(m);
                notifyList = observers;
            }
            // Problem here
            for_each(notifyList.begin(), notifyList.end(), 
                     mem_fun(&Observer::Notify));
        }
    }

private:
    set<Observer*> observers;
    thread t;
    mutex m;
};
```

**Edit**

I can't Notify observers while holding the mutex because of the deadlock risk.  The most obvious way this can happen - the client calls Subscribe or Unsubscribe from inside Notify - is easily remedied by making the mutex recursive.  More insidious is the risk of intermittent deadlock on different threads.

I'm in a multithreaded environment, so at any point in a thread's execution, it will typically hold a sequence of locks L1, L2, ... Ln.  Another thread will hold locks K1, K2, ... Km.  A properly written client will ensure that different threads will always acquire locks in the same order.  But when clients interact with my Subject's mutex - call it X - this strategy will be broken:  Calls to Subscribe / Unsubscribe acquire locks in the order L1, L2, ... Ln, X.  Calls to Notify from my Subject thread acquire locks in the order X, K1, K2, ... Km.  If any of the Li or Kj can coincide down any call path, the client suffers an intermittent deadlock, with little prospect of debugging it.  Since I don't control the client code, I can't do this.

Comment: I'm missing something. When would a specific observer unsubscribe some other observer? The specific observer should only be unsubscribing itself. The notifylist can only have the same observer once within it so how can the already fired notify become stale?

Comment: The client can Unsubscribe an Observer at any time, not just inside a Notify.  It is in this general case that we get the race against the Subject thread.

Comment: @fizzer: it is unclear here how you have implemented memory safety. How do you guarantee that all `Observer*` in `observers` point to valid instance of `Observer`?

Comment: @Matthieu. It's just the client's responsibility. Let's say an instance is allocated on the thread which calls Subscribe(), and, for the sake of simplicity, the same client thread wants to destroy the instance after calling Unsubscribe(). When, if ever, it is safe to perform that deletion is one of the points of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "ideal" solution would involve using `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr`. However, in order to be generic, it also has to account for the issue of `Subject` being dropped before some of its `Observer` (yes, that can happen too).

```
class Subject {
public:
    void Subscribe(std::weak_ptr<Observer> o);
    void Unsubscribe(std::weak_ptr<Observer> o);

private:
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::set< std::weak_ptr<Observer> > observers;
};

class Observer: boost::noncopyable {
public:
    ~Observer();

    void Notify();

private:
    std::mutex;
    std::weak_ptr<Subject> subject;
};
```

With this structure, we create a cyclic graph, but with a judicious use of `weak_ptr` so that both `Observer` and `Subject` can be destroyed without coordination.

*Note: I have assumed, for simplicity, that an `Observer` observes a single `Subject` at a time, but it could easily observe multiple subjects.*

---

Now, it seems that you are stuck with unsafe memory management. This is a quite difficult situation, as you can imagine. In this case, I would suggest an experiment: *an asynchronous `Unsubscribe`*. Or at least, the call to `Unsubscribe` will be synchronous from the outside, but be implemented asynchronously.

The idea is simple: we will use the event queue to achieve synchronization. That is:

- the call to `Unsubscribe` posts an event in the queue (payload `Observer*`) and then waits
- when the `Subject` thread has processed the `Unsubscribe` event(s), it wakes up the waiting thread(s)

You can use either busy-waiting or a condition variable, I would advise a condition variable unless performance dictates otherwise.

*Note: this solution completely fails to account for `Subject` dying prematurely.*

Comment: I don't want to assume an event queue, or impose particular ownership semantics on clients, but I like the idea that Unsubscribe() waits for the notify thread to ack the unsubscription.

Answer (score 7):

Unsubscribe() should be synchronous, so that it does not return until Observer is guaranteed not to be in Subject's list anymore. That's the only way to do it safely.

ETA (moving my comment to the answer):

Since time doesn't seem to be an issue, take and release the mutex between notifying each observer. You won't be able to use for_each the way you are now, and you'll have to check the iterator to ensure that it's still valid.

```
for ( ... )
{
    take mutex
    check iterator validity
    notify
    release mutex
}
```

That will do what you want.

Comment: Since time doesn't seem to be an issue, take and release the mutex between notifying each observer.

Comment: I want to avoid holding the mutex while calling client code because of the deadlock risk.

Comment: The client code you call should execute in the context of your thread, so it shouldn't be an issue. If it tries to take the same mutex, since it's the same thread it will succeed.

Comment: You can't know if the iterator is valid or not without knowing what every other thread is doing. Once you lose exclusive access to the container you have to be pessimistic and assume all iterators and references to elements in it are invalid.

Comment: I think that one can trust that if the pointer to observer is still in the observers list, that it's usable. So the only thing to check, once you've taken the mutex is if your current iterator is still good e.g. the observer* is still in the list.

Comment: Have you looked at a hand-over-hand locking mechanism for controlling access to the observer list?

Answer (score 3):

Can you change the signature of Subscribe() an Unsubscribe()? Replacing the Observer* with something like shared_ptr<Observer> would make things easier.

EDIT: Replaced "easy" by "easier" above.
For an example of how this is difficult to "get right", see the history of the [Boost.Signals](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/signals.html) and of the [adopted](http://lists.boost.org/boost-announce/2008/11/0211.php)-but-not-yet-in-the-distribution [Boost.Signals2](http://www.comedi.org/projects/signals2/libs/signals2/doc/html/) (formerly Boost.ThreadSafeSignals) libraries.

Comment: I thought about this - I could even hold weak_ptr in the Subject, and clients wouldn't even need to unsubscribe.  Unfortunately, I can't change this interface, but I will definitely do this in future.

Comment: I've built things a lot like this using shared_ptr & weak_ptr and they work well.  Too bad you can't change the API.

Comment: While this solves the "who deletes who" resource problem, without solving the synchronization problem you can still run into the situation where a notification happens on an observer that has already been unsubscribed - maybe thats not a problem.

Comment: @fizzer: note that by using `enable_shared_from_this` as a base class of `Observer` you would be able to easily retrofit this into your design (it would be source-compatible with client code).

Answer (score 1):

Mmm... I don't really understand your question, because if a client calls Unsubscribe you should be able to let the client delete it (it's not used by you). However, if for some reason you cannot close the relationship once the client unsubscribes the observer, you could add "Subject" a new operation to safely delete an Observer, or just for the clients to signal that they are not interested in an Observer any more.

*Rethink edit*: OK, now I think I understand what's your problem. I think the best solution to your problem is doing the following:

1. Have each stored observer element to have a "valid" flag. This flag will be used to notify it or not while you're in the notification loop.
2. You need a mutex to protect the access to that "valid" flag.  Then, the unsubscribe operation locks the mutex for the "valid" flag, sets it to false for the selected observer.
3. The notification loop also has to lock and unlock the mutex of the valid flag, and only act upon observers that are "valid".

Given that the unsubscribe operation will block on the mutex to reset the valid flag (and that that particular Observer won't be used any more in your thread), the code is thread safe, and clients can delete any observer as soon as unsubscribe has returned.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this be satisfactory? It still isn't safe to unsubscribe an observer while being notified though, for that you would need an interface like you mentioned (as far as I can tell).

```
Subscribe(Observer *x)
{
    mutex.lock();
    // add x to the list
    mutex.unlock();
}

Unsubscribe(Observer *x)
{
    mutex.lock();
    while (!ok_to_delete)
        cond.wait(mutex);
    // remove x from list
    mutex.unlock();
}

NotifyLoop()
{
    while (true) {
        // wait for something to trigger a notify

        mutex.lock();
        ok_to_delete = false;
        // build a list of observers to notify
        mutex.unlock();

        // notify all observers from the list saved earlier

        mutex.lock();
        ok_to_delete = true;
        cond.notify_all();
        mutex.unlock();
    }
}
```

If you want to be able to Unsubscribe() inside Notify() - *(a bad design decision on the client IMO...)* you can add the thread id of the notifier thread into your data structure. In the Unsubscribe function you can check that thread id against the current thread's id (most threading libraries provide this - eg. pthread_self). If they are the same, you can proceed without waiting on the condition variable.

NOTE: If the client is responsible for deleting the observer, this means you run into the situation where inside the Notify callback, you will have unsubscribed and deleted the observer, but are still executing something with that junked this pointer. It is something the client will have to be aware of and to only delete it at the end of the Notify().

Comment: But would'nt that deadlock if an Observer Unsubscribe()s itself from its Notify callback?

Comment: +1 as it addresses the crux of the problem.  I'd like clients to be able to subscribe from callbacks, though, so I'll need a bit more thinking.  It's scary that there's not a well-known idiom for this problem.  I see this pattern every day, always broken.

Comment: fizzer - subscribing from callbacks is fine. You don't need to ever wait on the condition variable when subscribing, only the mutex (which is explicitly release before calling Notify(). It is only unsubscribing that is the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the comment last thing at night.  I'd like Unsubscribe to work from callbacks.  Unsubscribing in response to an event is a very plausible thing for a client to try.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in responding.  I think it's almost there, except that the condition needs to prevent the client from returning (and potentially calling delete). So ok_to_delete needs to be false while in the Notify loop, and the client needs to wait for it *after* 'remove x from list'

Comment: It doesn't really matter if you wait on the condition before or after you remove them from the list in Unsubscribe. You can still potentially be executing something in Notify with the thing you are removing, and it still doesn't really matter. In fact it may be better to do it this way -

Comment: - because there is a lot smaller chance that you call unsubscribe, and then receive an event, and then are notified still (note Unsubscribe still hasn't returned). The *Gotcha* is still Unsubscribing and deleting that pointer inside Notify().

Comment: Suppose the notify thread is calling observer's notify code (at your comment 'notify all observers from the list saved earlier'), so ok_to_delete is false.  At this point, some other thread calls unsubscribe while holding a lock L, so it blocks on the condition.  If the notify code now tries to acquire L, there will be a deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than have clients get a "SafeToDelete" notification, provide them with an IsSubscribed( Observer *) method. The client  code then becomes:

```
subject.Unsubscribe( obsever );l
while( subject.IsSubscribed( observer ) ) {
   sleep_some_short_time;   // OS specific sleep stuff
}
delete observer;
```

which is not too onerous.

Comment: If IsSubscribed() simply looks in the set of observers, it's still broken.  The whole thing could complete while the Subject thread is asleep at the 'Problem here' comment in the example code I've posted.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a "to-delete queue" in the CSubject type. When you remove the the Observer, you could call pSubject->QueueForDelete(pObserver). Then when the subject thread is between notifications, it could safely delete observers from the queue.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does the trick if not very elegantly:

```
class Subject {
public:
Subject() : t(bind(&Subject::Run, this)),m_key(0)    {    }
void Subscribe(Observer* o) {
    mutex::scoped_lock l(m);
    InternalObserver io( o );
    boost::shared_ptr<InternalObserver> sp(&io);
    observers.insert(pair<int,boost::shared_ptr<InternalObserver>> (MakeKey(o),sp));
}

void Unsubscribe(Observer* o) {
    mutex::scoped_lock l(m);
    observers.find( MakeKey(o) )->second->exists = false;    }

void WaitForSomethingInterestingToHappen() {}
void Run()
{
    for (;;)
    {
        WaitForSomethingInterestingToHappen();
        for( unsigned int i = 0; i < observers.size(); ++ i )
        {
            mutex::scoped_lock l(m);
            if( observers[i]->exists )
            {
                mem_fun(&Observer::Notify);//needs changing
            }
            else
            {
                observers.erase(i);
                --i;
            }
        }
    }
}
private:

int MakeKey(Observer* o) {
    return ++m_key;//needs changeing, sha of the object?
}
class InternalObserver {
public:
    InternalObserver(Observer* o) : m_o( o ), exists( true ) {}
    Observer* m_o;
    bool exists;
};

map< int, boost::shared_ptr<InternalObserver> > observers;
thread t;
mutex m;
int m_key;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `observers` to a `map` with key `Observer*` and value a wrapper of `Observer`. The wrapper includes a `volatile` boolean to indicate if the `Observer` is valid. In `subscribe` method, the wrapper object is created in **valid** state. In `unsubscribe` method, the wrapper is marked as **invalid**. `Notify` is called on the **wrapper** instead of the **actual Observer**. The wrapper will call `Notify` on the **actual Observer** if it is valid (still subscribed)

```
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

class Observer
{
public:
    void Notify() {}
};

class ObserverWrapper : public Observer
{
public:
    Observer* wrappee;
    volatile bool valid;
    ObserverWrapper(Observer* o) 
    {
        wrappee = o;
        valid = true;
    }

    void Notify() 
    {
        if (valid) wrappee->Notify();
    }
}
class Subject
{
public:
    Subject() : t(bind(&Subject::Run, this))
    {
    }

    void Subscribe(Observer* o)
    {
        mutex::scoped_lock l(m);
        boost::shared_ptr<ObserverWrapper> sptr(new ObserverWrapper(o));
        observers.insert(pair<Observer*, sptr));
    }

    void Unsubscribe(Observer* o)
    {
        mutex::scoped_lock l(m);
        observers.find(o)->second->valid = false;
        observers.erase(o);
    }

    void Run()
    {
        for (;;)
        {
            WaitForSomethingInterestingToHappen();
            vector<ObserverWrapper*> notifyList;
            {
                mutex::scoped_lock l(m);
                boost::copy(observers | boost::adaptors::map_values, std::back_inserter(notifyList));
            }
            // Should be no problem here
            for_each(notifyList.begin(), notifyList.end(), 
                     mem_fun(&ObserverWrapper::Notify));
        }
    }

private:
    map<Observer*, ObserverWrapper*> observers;
    thread t;
    mutex m;
};
```

Comment: Nothing prevents a client thread unsubscribing if the subject thread gets suspended at the 'Should be no problem here' line.

Comment: @fizzer Yes, unsubscribe can happen. I believe that should not be a problem because the unsubscribe operation will set the valid flag in ObserverWrapper to false. So notify will not be called on the Observer.

Comment: My apologies. The vulnerability is between testing the valid flag and calling Notify on the wrappee.

Comment: Indeed! I did miss that.